# Explanation of Quran chapter 24 verses 6 -9

Tags: quran, tafseer, punishment, zina

Here Allah (swt) is talking about a situation of what muslims should do when a husband catches wife cheating on him and therefore can't produce 4 witnesses. My question is, if in verse 8 of this chapter Allah says,

> "But it will prevent punishment from her if she gives four testimonies [swearing] by Allah that indeed, he is of the liars"

, here the word punishment - does it mean the punishment of the hereafter or punishment of stoning?
Further more in verse 10 Allah says,

> "And if not for the favor of Allah upon you and His mercy... and because Allah is Accepting of repentance and Wise."

does this mean here that if either the accuser or the one being accused lies in his/her testimony... and if the liar recognizes his faults and wants to change and therefore repents to Allah and He will forgive him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by the reason for the revelation of the first verse:

> 'Abdullah reported:
>   We were on the night of Friday staying in the mosque when a person from the Ansar came there and said: If a person finds his woman along with a man, and he speaks about it, you would lash him, and if he kills, you will kill him, and if he keeps quiet he shall have to consume anger. By Allah, I will definitely ask about him from Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). On the following day he came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and asked him thus: If a man were to find with his wife a man and if he were to talk about it, you would lash him; and if he killed, you would kill him, and if he were to keep quiet. he would consume anger, whereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: Allah, solve (this problem), and he began to supplicate (before Him), and then the verses pertaining to li'an were revealed:
>   " Those who accuse their wives and have no witnesses except themselves" (xxiv. 6).
>   The person was then put to test according to these verses in the presence of the people. There came he and his wife in the presence of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and they invoked curses (in order to testify their claim). The man swore four times in the name of Allah that he was one of the truthful and then invoked curse for the fifth time saying: Let there be curse of Allah upon him if he were among the liars. Then she began to invoke curse. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to her: just wait (and curse after considering over it), but she refused and invoked curse and when she turned away, he (Allah's Apostle) said: It seems that this woman shall give birth to a curly-haired black child, And so she did gave birth to a curly-haired black child.
>   (In [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/19/13), but also different versions  in Sunan abi Dawod[1](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/79) [2](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/80) [3](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/82), Jami' at-Tirmidhi [1](https://sunnah.com/urn/742050) [2](https://sunnah.com/urn/742040) [3](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/13/29) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1321460))

**here the word punishment - does it mean the punishment of the hereafter or punishment of stoning?**

of course the punishment referred to here is that of this life as in the hereafter four witnesses are not needed to come to a verdict and punishment (hadd). Imam ibn Kathir said:

> (*But she shall avert the punishment*)
>   meaning, the prescribed punishment.
>   (*if she bears witness four times by Allah, that he is telling a lie. And the fifth; should be that the wrath of Allah be upon her if he speaks the truth.*)
>   The wrath of Allah is mentioned specially in the case of the woman, because usually a man would not go to the extent of exposing his wife and accusing her of Zina unless he is telling the truth and has good reason to do this, and she knows that what he is accusing her of is true. So in her case the fifth testimony calls for the wrath of Allah to be upon her, for the one upon whom is the wrath of Allah, is the one who knows the truth yet deviates from it. (Source [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2443&Itemid=79))

Some of the longer narrations (qualified as da'if?) show that the woman who was involved in the situation has chosen not to disgrace her people and seemingly preferred the punishment in the hereafter or had hope in Allah's mercy if she repented:

> …
>   Then the woman got up and took the oaths, and when she was about to take the fifth one; That the wrath of Allah be upon her if he speaks the truth', the people stopped her and said to her: 'It will definitely bring about Allah's curse upon you (if you are guilty).'" Ibn 'Abbas said 'So she hesitated, and recoiled so much so, that we thought that she would withdraw her denial. But she said: 'I will not dishonor my family for the rest of their days.'
>   … (See for example in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/742050))

**does this mean here that if either the accuser or the one being accused lies in his/her testimony... and if the liar recognizes his faults and wants to change and therefore repents to Allah and He will forgive him.**

First be aware that both parties if they have sworn a fifth time have saved themselves from a severe punishment. But certainly one of them might have lied.
This *may* mean if one of these people when asked to do his fifth oath came to mind and told the truth instead of lying Allah may forgive him (in the hereafter) no matter if he/she will be punished by stoning or being lashed as stated in another sahih hadith which is included in some of the longer versions of the hadith quoted above:

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
>   Hilal bin Umaiya accused his wife before the Prophet (ﷺ) of committing illegal sexual intercourse with Sharik bin Sahma.' The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Produce a proof, or else you would get the legal punishment (by being lashed) on your back." Hilal said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! If anyone of us saw another man over his wife, would he go to search for a proof." The Prophet (ﷺ) went on saying, "**Produce a proof or else you would get the legal punishment (by being lashed) on your back**." The Prophet (ﷺ) then mentioned the narration of Lian (as in the Holy Book). (Surat-al-Nur: 24) ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/33))

But let's look in books of tafssir for a better understanding:
Ibn Kathir says in his tafssir:

> (*And that Allah is the One Who forgives and accepts repentance,)*
>   means, from His servants, even if that comes after they have sworn a confirmed oath. (Source: [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2443&Itemid=79))

Some scholars like at-Tabari and al-Baghawi say: the meaning of this verse is that Allah's mercy here is that by the procedure of L'ian اللعان he saved both from disgrace by revealing their sins and from a severe punishment this life so one should be thankful and perform repentance hoping Allah might accept it in the hereafter. So the procedure of Li'an even if it separates husband and wife forever it saves both from disgrace and a big harm in this life and it also gives the liar a second chance to repent while he is alive.

Some others like al-Mawardi gave two possible interpretations of Allah's mercy : the first is that Allah gave both the option and time to repent instead of being punished (soon in this life) and the second is that were there not His mercy the liar would have received a severe punishment.

Comment: Thanks so much for a very academic answer... I was going crazy since yesturday to understand these couple of verses. Jazakallah khair! I had another question... so what is the actual point of L'ian... is it to disclose the truth of who is guility (and therefore the guilty to be stoned) or it's is to protect the honor of both (so even if the result of L'ian is separation forever, the liar can still seek repentance from Allah swt)

Comment: And BTW what happened to Hilal bin Umaiya 's wife after everyone found out that her child is not Hilal's....since the proof is estabilished, will the punishment of stoning be carried or by the mercy of Allah after she testified against her husband, she can can will towards repenting to Allah

Comment: Your question about the hadith should be asked separately. Li'an is to separate between two spouses when one of them (husband) accuses the other (wife) to have performed adultery and has no witnesses or proof. As the harmony of this household would be destroyed by this accusation be it true or false so this marriage couldn't carry on.

Comment: Based on islamic traditions we are aware that it's virtuous to cover up one's faults... if a husband see her wife commit such a hideous action, if he choses to cover up her faults and divorce... does the questioning of divorce lead towards the procedure of l'ian

Comment: That's again a different question which should be discussed separately :)

Comment: Ok so let me get this straight... with verse 10 we can be clear that even if either the wife or husband lies in their testimony, and the guilty genuinely lies in the hope of turning to Allah in sincere repentance she can do that cuz "Allah is ever accepting of repentance". But say if the guilty, when saying their 5th testimony things that he or she feels so bad and he/she can't come out of this burden of sin... they confess so they get washed of their sin in this life and relieve from the punishment of the sin in the next....

Comment: Essentially...can we say here that Allah (swt) is simply opening up the options towards both parties so they can deal with it accordingly?

Comment: Be aware that once each of the parties have pronounced their fifth testimony in case of pregnancy the child will not have the name of the husband who initiated l'ian and there's no inheritance between these parties. And furthermore no matter what happend both former husband and wife will leave each other in a honorable and respectful manner and none is allowed to accuse any of them later so they must be treated respectfully. So the future of the liar is in the hand of Allah and anything else would be a guess from my side.